# How to send an SMS from Android emulator to a cellphone

Tags: android, sms, emulation

I am trying to send an SMS to a cellphone but I have a problem: I can't receive a message but  the emulator tells me the message has been sent.

Here is my code,

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;

public class sendsms extends Activity {
  Button buttonSend;
  EditText textPhoneNo;
  EditText textSMS;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sending);
    buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BTNSENDSMS);
    textPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEnterNoSMS);
    textSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMsgSMS);
    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        String phoneNo = textPhoneNo.getText().toString();
        String sms = textSMS.getText().toString();
        try {
          SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
          smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SMS faild, please try again later!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.sdc"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 8):

**No**, you can not send SMS from an emulator to a cell phone, the simple and logical reason is that the emulators don't have a **SIM Card**.

However you can send SMS from one emulator to another assuming that both instances are running on the same computer.

Comment: yes, but it is very long process with web service and GSM Modem.

Answer (score 6):

By no way you can send sms from emulator to actual phone, But you can send sms from one emulator to another (Provided two instance of emulators running)

Eg. 1st emulator running with emulator code (5554) and other running with (5556) and send sms from emulator 5554 to 5556

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have another phone why don't you try a web service to send SMS? I quickly googled something, maybe it's good enough:

http://www.txt2day.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to try and see, you can build your code to an .apk file and then try running that app in some actual android phone.